# yq v4: delete node based on key-value of child

Tags: yaml, yq

How can I remove **all** (parent) nodes with the "type: array" key/value pair using yq v4?

**Before:**

```
info:
  title: My API
components:
  schemas:
    pets:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/pet"
    pet:
      type: object
      properties:
        petName:
          type: string
```

**After:**

```
info:
  title: My API
components:
  schemas:
    pet:
      type: object
      properties:
        petName:
          type: string
```

I use yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version v4.30.8

I tried many yq commands, for example:

```
yq 'del(.components.schemas.[] | select(. == "array") | parent)' filename.yaml
```

, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I remove **all** (parent) nodes with the "type: array" key/value pair

To reach **all** items, use `..` to [recurse down](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/recursive-descent-glob) the document tree. To filter for a given key/value pair, name key and value on both sides of the equation.

```bash
yq 'del(.. | select(.type == "array"))' file.yaml
```

EDIT: [How to only consider nodes under `.components.schemas`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75298916/yq-v4-delete-node-based-on-key-value-of-child#comment132869839_75299005)

If you still want recursion, prepend `..` with `.components.schemas |`. Without recursion, replace `..` with `.components.schemas[]`.

```bash
yq 'del(.components.schemas | .. | select(.type == "array"))' file.yaml
```

```bash
yq 'del(.components.schemas[] | select(.type == "array"))' file.yaml
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I fixed the yaml syntax error.
Your command deletes nodes in the entire document.
How can I only delete nodes under components.schemas ?
`yq 'del(.components.schemas | select(.type == "array"))' file.yaml`
doesn't work.

Comment: The following command, only deletes nodes under components,schemas:
`yq 'del(.components.schemas | .. | select(.type == "array"))' file.yaml`